# Crossing from Thailand to Cambodia with a motorbike scooter registered in Thailand

Tags: driving, borders, thailand, cambodia

I have a 125 cc scooter registered in Thailand. If I ride it to the border with Cambodia, can I cross the border, visit Cambodia for some weeks and drive back?

I am concerned with the vehicle more than the driving license. So this question is not about the driving license but the vehicle.

Comment: I doubt it.  I have crossed from Thailand to Cambodia by land.  Very little motor traffic crossed except for Thai trucks with building materials.  I did not see any personal vehicles crossing.  I cannot say that it is impossible which is why this us a comment rather than an answer but it is rare at best.

Comment: Thank's man. Let's see if someone can bring in more info. I read in forum many Westener who bought big bikes and registered in Thailand claim to go travelling to Cambodia with them. Let's see.

Comment: There is an answer here: https://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/727113-driving-a-small-thai-motorcycle-or-scooter-into-cambodia/ but a bit outdated. Let's see if someone has new info

Comment: Of course, in this region what is theoretically allowed and what actually happens don't always match.  You may be stopped doing something that should be allowed or ignored doing something that you should not.

Comment: I've seen it done in Poipet (I just crossed on foot myself). You need all papers, in your name, which seems to be the most important part. There will be a nominal fee.

Comment: yes, i have seen it in Poipet too. And if i am not mistaken, we allowed to bring vehicle there. the thing that matters is your password and all your papers with your name on it and the money as well :)

Answer (score 1):

[Thai Customs](http://en.customs.go.th/content.php?ini_content=individuals_151007_01&lang=en&left_menu=menu_individuals_151007_01) considers this a temporary import of a personal vehicle, and there are quite a few regulations, clearance procedures, and guarantees imposed:

> **IMPORTING PERSONAL VEHICLES**
>
> A temporary import of personal vehicles for a short visit e.g. a motor vehicle, motorcycle, yacht, sports boat, or fishing vessel, etc. into Thailand by owners shall be grant tax/duty relief provided that they are to be re-exported within 1-2 months but not exceeding six months. Any persons intending to temporarily import personal vehicles e.g. a motor vehicle, motorcycle, yacht, sports boat, or fishing vessel, etc. have to closely observe the following Customs regulations and conditions:
>
> **Documents:** The minimum documents required for a temporary import of personal vehicles consist of:
>
> - A Special Goods Declaration and 5 duplicates;
> - A Vehicle Registration Certificate;
> - An Identification card and passport of the master of the vehicle, including an international driving license;
> - A Letter of Attorney, in case where the master of the vehicle does not own the vehicle;
> - An application form for the temporary import of personal vehicles;
> - Evidence of purchase e.g. a proforma invoice, invoice, etc;
> - A Certificate of Legal Entity;
> - A Re-Export Contract; and
> - Other relevant documents (if any).
>
> **Clearance Procedures for a Temporary Import of Personal Vehicles**
>
> - An importer/agent submits the Declaration Form and all supporting documents to the Customs office/house at the port of entry. It is also required that all fittings and accessories of the vehicle as well as passengers and accompanying luggage are declared to Customs at the time of entry.
> - Customs verifies the Declaration Form and all supporting documents, allocates the Declaration number, and then set up a cash deposit or bank guarantee covering the full amount of liable taxes and duties.
> - The importer/agent places the cash deposit or bank guarantee at a Cashier Office.
>
> **Deposit of Guarantee**
>
> - An importer is allowed to deposit a guarantee in a form of either cash deposit or a bank guarantee. However, for a temporary import of motorcycles via the Bangkok Port Customs Office and the Suvanabhumi International Airport Cargo Clearance Customs Office, the importer is allowed to offer himself as a guarantee.
> - In case where the importer is unable to deposit a guarantee either in a form of a cash deposit or a bank guarantee, he/she may request the embassy to issue a letter to Customs granting approval of the importer s self-guarantee.
> - The amount of a cash deposit and a guarantee calculated by Customs is determined on the basis of all liable taxes and duties to be paid to Customs.
> - The importer/agent presents evidence of deposited guarantee to Customs.
> - Customs inspects the vehicle and personal belongings, then, returns one copy of the Simplified Goods Declaration to the importer/agent. Please note that the importer is required to retain the copy of the Simplified Goods Declaration and return it to Customs upon exportation.